# BIOS boot manager for Windows Vista Boot Camp Macbook partition

Tags: windows-vista, macbook, bios, boot-manager

I am trying to find the BIOS boot manager for my Windows Vista Boot Camp partition of my Macbook. How do I access this during sartup?

Comment: what does BIOS have to do with windows?